# Flutter Firestore app slow performance issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

We are developing an flutter app (Pixz:- [android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pixz.io.pixz) & [iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pixz-group-event-photos/id1491306184?ls=1)) and everything works fine except the firestore queries. When we launch the app for the first time everything is smooth and run fine but after a while firestore queries jams the app. Simple save query takes 5 minutes to execute. See query below

---SAVE QUERY---

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Groups').document(groupID).setData({
  'id': groupID,
  'created_by': currentUser.uid,
  'title': titleText.text,
  'description': descriptionText.text,
  'isPrivate': true,
  'status': 1,
  'created_at': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
  'updated_at': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
  }).then((response) {
     print('success);
  }).catchError((error) {
     print('error);
  });
```

I upgraded to latest packages see below versions of Packages and also upgraded Flutter to latest stable version but no luck.

---VERSIONS---

```
firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
firebase_storage: ^3.1.5
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
firebase_messaging: ^6.0.13
firebase_remote_config: ^0.3.0+3
firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.3+3
firebase_analytics: ^5.0.11
```

I read online about disabling the offline persistence but firestore package has deprecated the use.

Kindly suggest if someone has gone through similar problem.

[Video URL](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pixz-92afa.appspot.com/o/Issues%2FScreen%20Recording%202020-05-29%20at%201.58.59%20PM.mov?alt=media&token=84e7be7f-aa08-44f9-98f7-c7e49f058aa5)

Comment: did you try on a real device, is there a problem with your internet connection ?

Comment: Yes I tested on real device and not problem with internet connection

Comment: The code you shared looks fine, and is extremely unlikely to cause slowness. How did you measure the time it takes to save the data? Please ensure to include have **everything** necessary for us to reproduce the problem in your question.

Comment: How did you measure the time it takes to save the data?:- I debugged my code it takes time to go to success message

Comment: It also take more time to getting the Document Snapshot and Query Snapshot

Comment: [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices) you may find the best practices documentation when writing an application that uses Firestore. In addition to that, I stumbled across [this](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow-e081fb8e55dd) article regarding optimizing Firestore queries. I hope this information helps.